# jquery change function not working correctly with multiple class

Tags: javascript, jquery

please see the code .

```js
$(".test").on("click", function() {
  var sclass = $(this).attr("class").split(" ")[1];
  $(".color").trigger("click");

  $(".color").on("change", function() {
    var scolor = $(this).val();
    $("." + sclass).css("background-color", scolor);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="color" name="color" class="color"><br><br>
<div class="test test1">hii</div><br><br>
<div class="test test2">hello</div>
```

here i need to change the background color of the div by selecting color . But when i am selecting color for one div then this color is effected to two ? what is the error in this code ?

Answer (score 1):

You should use **off** and then **on**

```js
$(".test").on("click", function() {
  var $el=$(this);
  $(".color").off("change").on("change", function() {
     $el.css("background-color",  $(this).val());
  }).click();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="color" name="color" class="color"><br><br>
<div class="test test1">hii</div><br><br>
<div class="test test2">hello</div>
```

Comment: I'm using one and not on. Do you know the difference?

Comment: You're wrong! He can change it when he wants... try my snippet. And please, read more about the meaning of "arrogance".

Comment: He needs to change the color only on the div click.

Comment: Exactly what he needs. We will see.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan sorry, but in this answer, there's no event on the colour input.  The recurring event is on the div.click, which sets up a single change on the colour input (one) for that div.  Clicking the colour input has no effect on the order of events.  You only need to click the div to change colour, then click the div again to change it again.

Comment: @Vixed having said the above, your code does not work if the user clicks "cancel" on the dialog as the "one" does not fire, so is still waiting until they next click "ok".  So: user clicks div1, selects green, cancel, clicks div 2, selects red, clicks ok, *both* events fire, colour is now red, *both* divs are red.  Surely this is *not* what the user would want?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan not sure why you think that, the click event is `on` not `one`, so always fires creating a new color-change-handler each time (not withstanding the issue with cancel).

Comment: So could just use `off()` with `on()` :)

Comment: @Vixed you're completely right, my mistake entirely. Apologies for that. However your original version using `one()` had the behaviour I described where the colour didn't change on second click, but it seems to be an issue in Chrome on OSX with the colour picker. Just FYI, the downvote isn't mine, otherwise I would have removed it

Answer (score 1):

In order to understand this bug, you will need to understand Javascript closures. There's a good link here that explains it, and it reveals this is a pretty easy mistake to make ([link to MDN closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops_A_common_mistake)).

You're creating closures when you assign these functions to those events , and each closure shares the same environment. Essentially `sclass` will be equal to `test test2` regardless. You're selection in `$("." + sclass)` will expand to `$(.test test2)`. Also you may need to include quotes in your jQuery selection.

Comment: While interesting, it's not the issue here.  The issue is that using `on` leaves the event handler behind, so the 2nd click still fires for the first div (ie on 2nd click, there are 2 change handlers rather than just the one for the current div).

Comment: For future reference: you've detailed what could be causing the issue, which is great, but you've not provided info on how to *fix* the issue, ie an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is because you add a new `change` handler to the color input on each click. This means the first handler is attached to the `.test1` element when you create a new one on `.test2`. This is why both elements are then effected by the change.

You need to move the `change` handler outside of the `click` handler. You can then just store the reference of the element directly instead of a class. Try this:

```js
$(".test").on("click", function() {
  $(".color").data('el', $(this)).trigger("click");
});

$(".color").on("change", function() {
  var $el = $(this).data('el');
  $el && $el.css("background-color", this.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="color" name="color" class="color"><br><br>
<div class="test test1">hii</div><br><br>
<div class="test test2">hello</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't need a global var

Comment: could you please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56404480/change-button-style-inside-paypal-i-frame-using-jquery-not-working