# Change button style inside paypal i frame using jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, paypal

i have following iframe in my website

```html
<iframe class="zoid-component-frame zoid-visible" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" name="test" title="ppbutton" scrolling="no" allowpaymentrequest="allowpaymentrequest" src="https://www.paypal.com/webapps/hermes/button?env=production&amp;commit=true&amp;style.label=pay&amp;style.layout=vertical&amp;style.size=responsive&amp;style.shape=rect&amp;style.color=gold&amp;style.tagline=false&amp;locale.x=en_US&amp;funding.disallowed=credit%2Cvenmo&amp;domain=store17204827.ecwid.com&amp;sessionID=93bede67c2_mdy6mzk6mdg&amp;buttonSessionID=c3989cbef7_mdy6mzk6mdg&amp;logLevel=warn&amp;sdkMeta=eyJ1cmwiOiJodHRwczovL3d3dy5wYXlwYWxvYmplY3RzLmNvbS9hcGkvY2hlY2tvdXQubWluLmpzIn0%3D&amp;uid=645255e5ef&amp;version=min&amp;xcomponent=1" style="background-color: transparent;"></iframe>
```

If you run the code here you can see there is a button coming . I want to change the yellow button text as "pay with debit or credit card" .i tried things but noting work . I try to hide the button log that also not working . Please see our code

```
$(".zoid-component-frame.zoid-visible").bind("load",function(){
        alert();
    $(this).contents().find(".paypal-button-logo-gold").css("display","none");
});
```

Please help to solve this issue .

Answer (score 1):

we cannot change the iframe content getting from other domain
CHeck this link
[How to change style of iframe content cross-domain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724904/how-to-change-style-of-iframe-content-cross-domain)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up doing to get my hosting site to control the styles in my zoid component:

1. In the hosting (React) app, when rendering the zoid component, I stringify'ed an object with the desired react styles:

```
const styles = JSON.stringify({ width:'100%', borderRadius: '0.25rem'});
```

2. These stringify'ed styles are then provided to the zoid component via the buttonStyles prop:

```
<MyReactComponent
  buttonText='Login'
  buttonStyles={styles}
></MyReactComponent>
```

3. Render code in the child site:

```
const renderContent = () => {
const styles = (props?.buttonStyles) ? JSON.parse(props.buttonStyles) : {};
  return <>
    <button
      style={styles}
      onClick={handleClick} 
      type='submit'
    >{props.buttonText || 'Sign In'}</button>
  </>
};
```